# SSH to Linux host with smart card, is not working

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, smartcard

I would like to connect to ssh host using the following command:

```
ssh -I /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so HOSTNAME
```

The error says that the library returned no slots..

> debug1: provider /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so:
>   manufacturerID  cryptokiVersion 2.20
>   libraryDescription  libraryVersion 0.17
>   debug1: pkcs11_add_provider: provider
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so returned no slots

The command to list readers works ok and I can see the slot - it's there.

```
$ opensc-tool --list-readers
# Detected readers (pcsc)
Nr.  Card  Features  Name
0    Yes             Gemalto USB Shell Token V2 00 00
```

What could be the reason for this?

This might be releated: [How can I set up smart card SSH authentication?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/342/how-can-i-set-up-smart-card-ssh-authentication/398)

===========================EDIT================================

I officially gave up on this.

Answer (score 2):

The message from `opensc-tool --list-readers`  indicates the reader is present and sees the card.

But the "slots" in the error message refer to a higher-level abstraction: the programmable "key slots" on the card itself. You could view them with `pkcs11-tool --list-slots` or `pkcs11-tool --list-token-slots`.

You might also want to run `opensc-tool --name`  to verify that the card type has been identified correctly.

Comment: Yeah --list-token-slots returns "Available slots: No slots.". Should I just give up?

Comment: "Gemalto USB Shell Token V2" is apparently an old name for "Gemalto IDBridge K30". Is it supposed to be ready for use (already provisioned), or is it a "blank" card that would need initialization? [OpenSC has a QuickStart document you might want to read.](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki/Quick-Start-with-OpenSC)

Comment: I'm only getting "Failed to connect to card: Internal error" with all this opensc-tool eg.: "opensc-tool --reader 0 --name" , the manual you've linked is apparently not for me. I get stuck at "opensc-tool --reader 0 --atr" with exactly the same 'Internal' error. I'm almost sure the USB is already provisioned and it all worked on Windoz. :(

Answer (score 1):

From https://piv.idmanagement.gov/engineering/ssh/#ssh-from-macos and works pretty much the same on linux:

1. Install OpenSC.
2. Insert your PIV/CAC into your card reader.
3. To view the certificates on your Mac, enter:

   pkcs15-tool --list-public-keys
4. Make note of the PIV AUTH pubkey  ID number.
5. Using reader with a card: SCR35xx Smart Card Reader

```
 Public RSA Key [PIV AUTH pubkey]
     Object Flags   : [0x0]
     Usage          : [0xD1], encrypt, wrap, verify, verifyRecover
     Access Flags   : [0x2], extract
     ModLength      : 2048
     Key ref        : 154 (0x9A)
     Native         : yes
     ID             : 01 (EXAMPLE ONLY)
     DirectValue    : <absent>
```

6. Use your PIV AUTH pubkey  ID number to view your SSH key. Enter:

   pkcs15-tool --read-ssh-key 01
7. When prompted, enter your PIV/CAC PIN. The SSH key will look like this:

   ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCyPn2dShOFLBnMraiP2MnLU ....
8. Copy the SSH key and paste it into a text file.
9. Send the text file to the server administrator and request a new account.
10. Once you have an account, you can log into the remote server. Enter:

    ssh -I /usr/lib64/opensc-pkcs11.so @
11. Optionally, you can update the setting in the /etc/ssh_config file to:

    PKCS11Provider /usr/lib64/opensc-pkcs11.so
12. Enter your PIV/CAC PIN when prompted. Once it’s validated, you’ll be logged into the remote server.

Comment: I fail at first step (pkcs15-tool --list-public-keys). Error says: Failed to connect to card: Internal error